# Translate automatic strings from features in WordPress permalink

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm developping a website in French so I look for all strings to translate them into French. I'm using some features that come along with the WP theme but I got English words in the URL. For instance, if I use the "My team" feature to display team members, I got a page with the following URL:

www.domain-name.fr/services-view/creation-sites-web/ (has "services-view")

I'd like to change "/services-view/ into "/nos-services/" (in order to have an URL which would look like : www.domain-name.fr/nos-services/creation-sites-web/.

Since this feature is not a separate plugin and doesn't work with categories, I don't know where to modify it. I checked the .po files and the function.php file without any success.

Does anyone have the solution ? Many thanks in advance !